# Paint bucket getting "Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded" error

Tags: javascript, recursion, drawing, p5.js, flood-fill

This is the code of the paint bucket tool in my drawing app using the p5.js library. The function **self.floodFill** always get "Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded" because of recursion and I want to know the way to fix it. I am thinking if changing the function to a no recursion function would help or not. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function BucketTool(){
    var self = this;
    //set an icon and a name for the object
    self.icon = "assets/bucket.jpg";
    self.name = "Bucket";
    var d = pixelDensity();
    
    var oldColor;
    var searchDirections = [[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]];
    
    var pixelsToFill = [];
    var positionArray = new Array(2);
    
    self.checkBoundary = function(currentX, currentY, localOldColor) {
        if (self.getPixelAtXYPosition(currentX,currentY).toString() != localOldColor.toString() || currentX < 0 || currentY < 0 || currentX > width || currentY > height || pixelsToFill.indexOf(currentX+" "+currentY) != -1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
    
    self.floodFill = function(currentX, currentY, localOldColor, localSearchDirections) {
        if (self.checkBoundary(currentX, currentY, localOldColor)){
            pixelsToFill.push(currentX+" "+currentY);
        } else {
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < searchDirections.length; i++){
            self.floodFill(currentX + searchDirections[i][0], currentY + searchDirections[i][1], localOldColor, localSearchDirections);
        }
    };
    
    self.getPixelAtXYPosition = function(x, y) {
        var colour = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < d; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            // loop over
            index = 4 * ((y * d + j) * width * d + (x * d + i));
            colour[0] = pixels[index];
            colour[1] = pixels[index+1];
            colour[2] = pixels[index+2];
            colour[3] = pixels[index+3];
          }
        }
        return colour;
    }
    
    self.drawTheNeededPixels = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < pixelsToFill.length; i++){
            positionArray = pixelsToFill[i].split(" ");
            point(positionArray[0],positionArray[1]);
        }
    }
    
    self.draw = function () {
        if(mouseIsPressed){
            pixelsToFill = [];
            
            loadPixels();
            
            oldColor = self.getPixelAtXYPosition(mouseX, mouseY);
            
            self.floodFill(mouseX, mouseY, oldColor, searchDirections);
            
            self.drawTheNeededPixels();
        }
        
    };
    
}
```

Comment: Can you provide rest of the javascript code. For example, how is `mouseIsPressed ` being evaluated ?

Comment: All the code references for the library are in https://p5js.org/. Such as `mouseIsPressed` is in https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseIsPressed. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're filling position `(x, y)`, then with direction `[1, 0]`, you're filling `(x + 1, y)`, and then with direction `[-1, 0]` you're filling `(x, y)`, then with direction `[1, 0]`, you're filling `(x + 1, y)`, then with direction `[-1, 0]`, you're filling `(x, y)`, then with...  You need to keep track of the ones you've filled.

Comment: The problem is I can fill without any error when I draw a small circle and click inside it. However, when I click on a larger space then it will get the error message immediately.

Comment: Can you try making a working example ? It will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is well documented on the [wikipedia page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Flood_fill) and the shortfalls of the different types of algorithms to perform flood filling. You've gone for the stack-based recursive implementation.

To prevent a stackoverflow — Maximum Call Stack Exceeded — the first step would be to use a data structure. Using queues/stacks rather than having the function call itself.

The code below creates an empty stack where we put a new object containing the x and y where the user has chosen to fill. This is then added to the `pixelsToFill` array. We then loop the stack until it's completely empty, at which point we are ready to display the filled pixels.

In the while loop we pop an element off the stack and then find its children — the directions up, down, left, right denoted by the `searchDirections` array you created. If we've not seen the child before and it's within the boundary we add it to the `pixelsToFill` array and add it to the stack to repeat the process:

```js
self.floodFill = function (currentX, currentY, localOldColor, localSearchDirections) {
    let stack = [];
    stack.push({ x: currentX, y: currentY });
    pixelsToFill.push(currentX + " " + currentY);
    while (stack.length > 0) {
      let current = stack.pop();
      for (var i = 0; i < searchDirections.length; i++) {
        let child = {
          x: current.x + searchDirections[i][0],
          y: current.y + searchDirections[i][1],
          localOldColor,
        };
        if (self.checkBoundary(child.x, child.y, localOldColor)) {
          pixelsToFill.push(child.x + " " + child.y);    
          stack.push(child);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

This code may stop the stackoverflow but there are still a lot of optimisations that can be made. Once again, it's worth checking out [the Wikipedia page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Flood_fill) and potentially take a look at Span filling.

```js
let bucketTool;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  bucketTool = new BucketTool();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  strokeWeight(5);
  circle(width / 2, height / 2, 100);
  frameRate(1);
  bucketTool.draw();
}

function BucketTool() {
  var self = this;
  //set an icon and a name for the object
  // self.icon = "assets/bucket.jpg";
  // self.name = "Bucket";
  var d = pixelDensity();

  var oldColor;
  var searchDirections = [
    [1, 0],
    [-1, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, -1],
  ];

  var pixelsToFill = [];
  var positionArray = new Array(2);

  self.checkBoundary = function (currentX, currentY, localOldColor) {
    if (
      self.getPixelAtXYPosition(currentX, currentY).toString() !=
        localOldColor.toString() ||
      currentX < 0 ||
      currentY < 0 ||
      currentX > width ||
      currentY > height ||
      pixelsToFill.indexOf(currentX+" "+currentY) != -1
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  self.floodFill = function (currentX, currentY, localOldColor, localSearchDirections) {
    let stack = [];
    stack.push({ x: currentX, y: currentY });
    pixelsToFill.push(currentX + " " + currentY);
    while (stack.length > 0) {
      let current = stack.pop();
      for (var i = 0; i < searchDirections.length; i++) {
        let child = {
          x: current.x + searchDirections[i][0],
          y: current.y + searchDirections[i][1],
          localOldColor,
        };
        if (self.checkBoundary(child.x, child.y, localOldColor)) {
          pixelsToFill.push(child.x + " " + child.y);    
          stack.push(child);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  self.getPixelAtXYPosition = function (x, y) {
    var colour = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < d; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < d; j++) {
        // loop over
        index = 4 * ((y * d + j) * width * d + (x * d + i));
        colour[0] = pixels[index];
        colour[1] = pixels[index + 1];
        colour[2] = pixels[index + 2];
        colour[3] = pixels[index + 3];
      }
    }
    return colour;
  };

  self.drawTheNeededPixels = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < pixelsToFill.length; i++) {
      positionArray = pixelsToFill[i].split(" ");
      point(positionArray[0], positionArray[1]);
    }
  };

  self.draw = function () {
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
      pixelsToFill = [];

      loadPixels();

      oldColor = self.getPixelAtXYPosition(mouseX, mouseY);
      self.floodFill(mouseX, mouseY, oldColor, searchDirections);

      console.log(pixelsToFill.length);
      self.drawTheNeededPixels();
    }
  };
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Shameless plug, but relevant: I've created a blog comparing the different [flood fill algorithms](https://codeheir.com/2022/08/21/comparing-flood-fill-algorithms-in-javascript/) using p5.js.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I know it is my problem but just want to know is there any way to make this faster as it is a bit slow when I try to click at a larger space. I did not receive an error message anymore but I need to wait like a minute before it gets filled.

Comment: `pop` is faster than `shift`.